# Jung Graph - Put one of node on top of others

Tags: java, nodes, jung, vertex

Since I customize the shape of the nodes when display those nodes, that causes some of the large nodes hide some small nodes. And also I was required to use static position which means I can not change the layout of it. So wondering has anyone tried to put one node on top of others by put something like priority.

I tried to add the larger nodes to the graph first followed by small nodes. or reverse order. It seems like this does not solve the problem. And searched over the internet, haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nodes to be rendered in a particular order, you will want to use an implementation of Graph that iterates over its nodes in a specified order, i.e., either a Sorted or an Ordered implementation.

The constraints that you're operating under (no control over size or position of vertices) make it sound as though your visualization is going to be kind of broken, though.